# Flutter Cloud-functions: How can I configure it to call functions running on localhost

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-functions, flutter-plugin

I am trying to remove all the hardcoded cloud functions url from my app so that I don't have to different config files for each environment. Since we use cloud functions as our backend, trying to use https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/cloud_functions plugin to achieve it. But could not figure out a way to call functions which are running locally.

Since we do lot of changes during development, it would be better if we are able to configure the callable url. thanks in advance

Comment: https://medium.com/better-programming/prototype-locally-with-flutter-and-firebase-db8907222bea

Answer (score 0):

you can check [ngrok](https://ngrok.com) for instance. It creates a tunnel from public address to localhost

Comment: Internally this plugin uses official library from firebase functions which has options set origin through [useFunctionsEmulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/functions/FirebaseFunctions.html#useFunctionsEmulator(java.lang.String)). So wanted to know the equivalent option in the flutter library.